# Code generation for caching purposes

Tags: php, caching, serialization, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I need to cache the results of a very expensive operation that involves scanning a directory and getting the contents of its files.

A good way to solve the problem is to cache the result in a php files. Since php files are loaded very quickly, I was thinking about serializing the whole array of result in a php-valid form, written to disk and ready to be included.

My question is: are there any tools/libraries/frameworks that perform the task of serialization in php code for caching purposes?
If not, what are the best practices to achieve this?

EDIT:

Thanks Jack for [var_export](http://www.php.net/var_export)!

Any ideas for how to add some code to the **symfony cc** in order to trigger the generation of this cache?

Comment: Which version of symfony?

Comment: Actually, is symfony 1.4.5-DEV

Comment: Have you looked at [`var_export()`](http://www.php.net/var_export)?

Comment: var_export is perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use symfony's [sfCache](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfCache) class. It can store and retrieve objects, and use various cache backends (you can use files, databases or APC as the backend)

Usage is simple: (I'm using [APC as cache storage](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfAPCCache), as APC is already enabled on my server. If you want to store data in files you can use [sfFileCache](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfFileCache))

```
$cache = new sfAPCCache();
if ($cache->has('data')) {
  return $cache->get('data');
} else {
  $data = calcualte_data();
  $cache->set('data',$data);
  return $data;
}
```